# Store a reference to a table in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

The goal I am trying to accomplish is to query from a table that is determined dynamically. Below is an example syntax of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
if exists (select * from tbl_first_option)
    set @tbl = tbl_first_option
else
    set @tbl = tbl_second_option

-- complex statement that selects from table
select * from @tbl
```

So instead of duplicating the complex statement I can use `@tbl`.
If there are better/easier ways of doing this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this without dynamic SQL, assuming the two tables have the same columns (or you can add/remove columns to match)

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  t.*
FROM (
    SELECT *, 1 AS TableNumber
    FROM tbl_first_option
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 2
    FROM tbl_second_option
) t
ORDER BY TableNumber;
```

Comment: If I want to add a where/join clause should it be inside the contained select and union or outside before the order by?

Comment: Inside would be best, although if you do it outside then in some situations the server is able to push it through

Answer (score 1):

You need a dynamic SQL query like

```sql
declare @SQL nvarchar(1000)
declare @tbl varchar(50)

if exists (select * from tbl_first_option)
    set @tbl = 'tbl_first_option'
else
    set @tbl = 'tbl_second_option'
 
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tbl)
 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Deleting your answer to remove downvotes is definitely not best practice and should not be done on this site!

Comment: People are free to downvote as they see fit - it's not for us to argue, nor delete our answers to avoid them.

Comment: `and my was correct from begining` - it wasn't, and it still isn't. `varchar(50)` is not the right data type to store a table name, like the [comment under your deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76278019/store-a-reference-to-a-table-in-a-variable/76278511#comment134511909_76278059) correctly suggests. Clearly you are only concerned with getting votes as opposed to the correctness of your content, so much so that you deleted your rightly downvoted answer and reposted it as is. I suggest you avoid posting here until you revise your approach.

Comment: it is clear there when  to downvote. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down my answer was not fiting into any of thease 2 criteria. please stop deleting this comment,  delete own if You have enough courage and simply say sorry.